# Custom Login Registration in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress, authentication, registration

I did Login, Registration in core php with validation, when user get registered, user data are stored in our mysql database.
After user registration, he can log-in through login form with the same data that already stored in the database while registering.
If user entered correct Username and Password in Login form then he will get successfully logged in.
In this case when user try to login at that time his credential is checked through fetched records from mysql database(from registered records).

But my query is i wants to build the same functionality (i.e. User registration and login) in WORDPRESS with registered user data are saved into the mysql database and that particular user try to login through LOGIN FORM he gets logged in when he is already registered user.
The user should be new member (custom user) not admin and all.

Means how to build custom Login Registration functionality with Mysql Databse (records saved while registering and user get logged in through the same credential).

I have searched related wordpress plugins for that, but they only sent email-notification while register and login, that i don't want actually.

Please suggest me the way to do.

Thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

If you are looking for a all-in-one plugin you can use [Ultimate Member](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ultimate-member/)

It serves with all the features you need. If for any reason the link does not work, you can search for "Ultimate Member" on wordpress.

This plugin serves the following purposes:

```
Front-end user registration
Front-end user login
Front-end user profiles
Custom form fields
Conditional logic for form fields
Drag and drop form builder
User account page
Custom user roles
Searchable member directories
Custom e-mail templates
Content restriction
Conditional menus
Show author posts & comments on user profiles
Mobile adaptive & responsive
SEO optimized
Developer friendly with dozens of actions and filters
Multi-site compatibility
Mandrill compatibility
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, i will check it.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @Andrew....i have used ultimate Member plugin, and trying to register it will display..."Registration is currently disabled" may be it takes user as admin that i don't want. Tell me what kind of setting i need to set for New custom user instead of admin.

Comment: You have to go through the ultimate member settings under wp-admin

Comment: I have giving Default New User Role as Member in member setting, but still it showing same "Registration is currently disabled". Could you please tell me all necessary settings that fulfill my requirements.